# Sharepoint WebService with Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, sharepoint

I have My Sharepoint Web Service URL, but when i try to access it i get HTTP Request Error. My Share point Webservice has credentials in it. I have also set that in Flex.

```
webService.setRemoteCredentials("CITMOSS\Administrator","Pa$$w0rd");
```

When i trace the url, my console does read the XML, but i am unable to call the method. It throws me HTTP Request Error.

Any Possible solutions on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access that web service manually from the same machine does it work?

Is there a way you could put something like Fiddler in the way to trace the network traffic and find out what is going on?

There are loads of things that could be causing a problem here, in Flex, in the web service and absolutely everywhere in between. Checking your event logs and sharepoint logs might also be informative, but if those yeild nothing then looking at the HTTP traffic will probably be most useful.